# Is there a difference between “living abroad” and “living offshore”?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

I was using always 'living abroad' and just found the expression: 'living offshore'. I would like to know if there's any difference between both. Can I use both expression as synonyms?

I know that 'abroad' means "foreign country". And offshore means also "in a foreign country", but with the associated connotation: *especially in order to take advantage of lower taxes or costs or less stringent regulation*.

So, if I'm living in another country, could I use interchangeably "I'm living abroad" and "I'm living offshore" or the second one will have a different connotation?

Could I use interchangeably: "There are 1 million Spaniards living abroad" and "There are 1 million Spaniards living offshore"?

**Context:** In an British film: (*The Night Manager, S01E01, Minute: 15:54*)
In a government agency, they receive information about one of the richest people in the world (Richard Roper), who is being investigated for arms trafficking. The boss asks an employee:

> Get me all the files you can on Richard Roper.
> ...
> Get Do a random sweep on all Brits living offshore.

Do are they doing a random sweep in all Brits living abroad? Or only in the ones that are 'rich' or have big companies and don't want to pay taxes?

Comment: Have you tried looking at a dictionary for the definitions of "offshore" and "abroad"?

Comment: A google search for "live offshore" gives links to sites about working and living on oil rigs. That would not be "living abroad".

Comment: @pboss3010 Yes, I did. It seems that offshore and abroad by themselves have different meanings, but, what I want to know if is a a sentence they're similar or not.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I have rewritten the question explaining better what my doubt is.

Comment: "Offshore" is usually applied to businesses, not individuals, so "living offshore" really does not sound natural.  Do you have an example of it being used in a context other than on oil rigs?

Comment: @CanadianYankee. Yes, In an English film, in a government agency, the boss asks an employee: Do a random sweep on all Brits living offshore.

Comment: Do you know from context whether the boss was referring to all Brits living abroad, or specifically ones living in [tax havens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_haven)?

Comment: @CanadianYankee I just added all the context. Just that is one of my questions/doubts that I couldn't get from context.

Comment: I was able to find a [longer quote](https://markham.bibliocommons.com/item/quotation/676844034) based on your excerpt: "So bury the requests in a pile of slurry. Do a random sweep on all Brits living offshore. Throw River House off the scent. Make us look like a bunch of amateurs looking for a needle in a haystack."  From this context, it looks like they're using it to mean exactly the same thing as "abroad" with no difference in meaning, since the intent is to make their efforts look incompetent.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Thank you very much for your explanations. As a Spanish speaker, I didn't realised that their intent was to make their efforts look incompetent!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Offshore" in reference to foreign countries is usually used more as a verb: "offshoring jobs" means to hire people in other countries (usually for cheaper wages or for tax/logistical benefits) and lay off domestic workers. As a native speaker of English (US), if you told me that you live offshore, I would take that to mean that you live on a boat or an oil rig, or perhaps on a very small island that is only reachable by boat.

Living abroad (or studying abroad) means what you have been saying: to reside in a foreign country, away from one's country of citizenship. That is the correct phrase. It generally implies an impermanent status: if a person has officially immigrated to where he now lives, you would usually not say that they are living abroad, but rather that they are an "expat" for [expatriate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expatriate) (which is a verb, an adjective, and (most frequently) a noun), or that they emigrated or moved to Spain (or wherever they happen to live now). So if I were to permanently move to Madrid and become a citizen of Spain, I would be called an "American expat", and people here in the US would say of me: "yeah, he moved to Spain." But if I were to retain my US citizenship without Spanish citizenship, and just live there for awhile, even if it were many years, then people would still say that I'm living abroad.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. What about the lower taxes connotation? Could be only a British and not American connotation/meaning?

Comment: Re taxes: "offshoring" has been a buzzword in American business media for quite some time.

And I would have to defer to a British person to talk about their interpretation specifically; while I have studied and traveled abroad, I have not done so in the UK, save for a 24 hour unplanned layover.

Comment: Actually, another time we often say offshore is in reference to bank accounts (again that gets to the tax or financial context): an "offshore account" is a bank account that is not accessible by the local authorities and does not operate domestically. Most commonly in Switzerland or Cayman Islands, maybe Macau or elsewhere in southeast Asia.